# JList in UI not reflecting changes from all peer processes

Tags: java, swing, client-server, jlist

I am writing a simple chat application in Java. As soon as a new user joins, the server component of my application should inform all other clients about this event.

The relevant code on the server side is as follows:

```
private void notifyUser() throws IOException {
    String[] user = new String[onlineUsers.size()];
    int i = 0;
    for(Socket sock : sockets){
        out.get(i).writeInt(1);
        out.get(i).writeObject(onlineUsers.toArray(user));
        out.get(i).flush();
    }
}
```

The client thread is listening on the socket using the following code:

```
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(sockfd.getInputStream());
while(true) {
    command = in.readInt();
    switch(command) {
        case 1:
            String[] user = (String[])in.readObject();
            System.out.println(user);
            client.addOnlineUsers(user);
    }
}
```

The `addOnlineUsers(..)` method consists of the following code:

```
public void addOnlineUsers(String[] user) {
    for(String s : user){
        listmodel.addElement(s);
    }
}
```

I have instantiated the JList like so:

```
JList list = new JList(listmodel);
```

, where `listmodel` is a public instance.

The problem is, however, that as soon as a new user joins the server, the `JList` of the 1st (i.e. the oldest) client is updated while the rest of the users don't receive any updates to the `JList` in their UI.

Comment: In the notifyUser method, you are only writing to the output stream of the first user in the array, i.e. `i = 0;` It should be incremented after `out.get(i).flush();`

Comment: No problem, just register this as the accepted answer so this question can be closed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the notifyUser method, you are only writing to the output stream of the first user in the array, i.e.

```
i = 0;
```

It should be incremented after

```
out.get(i).flush();
```